# Angular acceleration of a spool of thread

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

I *think* this is an easy question in rotational kinematics, but--I don't seem to be understanding it on a fundamental level:

[image: Question on the rotation of a spool of thread]

Here's my work:

$$ \tau \ =\ F\ r_1 $$
$$ \tau \ =\ I\ \alpha $$
$$ I\ \alpha \ =\ F\ r_1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{2}\ m\ r_1^2 \ \alpha \ =\ F\ r_1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{2}\ m\ r_1 \ \alpha \ =\ F $$
$$ \alpha \ =\ \frac{2\ F}{m\ r_1} $$
$$ \alpha \ =\ \frac{2\ (\ 0.650\ )}{(\ 0.230\ )\ (\ 0.078\ )} $$
$$ \alpha\ =\ 78.464\ s^{-2} $$

The book says the answer is in the neighborhood of 1 radian per second squared. Also--I haven't used the outer radius at all, which is a red flag.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 0):

Horizontally speaking, in addition to the applied force due to tension, there is another *backward static friction* applied on the contact point (because it is *stationary* due to *rolling without slipping*). So, don't ignore that force.

Answer (score 0):

You need to impose the no-slip condition. This means $v + \omega R_2 =0$ where $v$ is the velocity of the center (towards the right) and $\omega$ the rotational velocity (counter clockwise).

Next differentiate the above to get an expression connection linear and angular acceleration

$$a + {\alpha} R_2 =0$$

You also need a free body diagram (all quantities drawn positively)

[image: fbd]

Now you look at your equations of motion

$$ \begin{align} R + T &= m a \\ R R_2 + T R_1 & = I \alpha \end{align} $$

From the no slip conditions you use $a = - \alpha R_1$ above and solve the first equation for $R$

$$R = -m R_2 \alpha - T $$

Use the reaction $R$ in the second equation and collect the unknown $\alpha$ on the left hand side

$$ (I+m R_2^2) \alpha = -T (R_2-R_1) $$

Solve for the angular acceleration (which is negative, or clockwise)

$$ \alpha = -\frac{T (R_2-R_1)}{I+m R_2^2} $$

Comment: So you actually wind up the thread around the spool in this no-slip case!